# React Native upgrade to 0.70.0 from 0.63.0, the demo so is crash when migrate to my Application

Tags: react-native

```js
12-27 18:02:45.939 13433 13903 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN8facebook5react5Props24enablePropIteratorSetterE" referenced by "/data/app/~~UXICWlN_UKU59_9hXpY4bQ==/com.myapplication.debug-LkEnUR2BWD8es6bfKiU1DQ==/lib/arm64/libsampleapp_appmodules.so"...
12-27 18:02:45.939 13433 13903 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:929)
12-27 18:02:45.939 13433 13903 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1620)
12-27 18:02:45.939 13433 13903 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader$1.load(SoLoader.java:650)
12-27 18:02:45.939 13433 13903 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource.loadLibraryFrom(DirectorySoSource.java:115)
12-27 18:02:45.939 13433 13903 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource.loadLibrary(DirectorySoSource.java:68)
12-27 18:02:45.939 13433 13903 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.soloader.ApplicationSoSource.loadLibrary(ApplicationSoSource.java:92)
12-27 18:02:45.939 13433 13903 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:1168)
12-27 18:02:45.939 13433 13903 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 15 more
```

and enablePropIteratorSetter is never used in libsampleapp_appmodules.so

Comment: Did you use the React Native Upgrade Helper to upgrade your app? I don't see anything about it on [diff 0.63.0 to 0.70.0](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.63.0&to=0.70.0). Maybe you need should run a `./gradlew clean` on your android project and run the project again

Comment: thanks, the reason is I use a mismatch ReactNative version with sample demo version.

Answer (score 0):

I had download a demo by this command:

```
npx react-native init SampleApp --version 0.70.0
```

then build output a libsampleapp_appmodules.so by codegen,
and I migrate the so to my application. but my ReactNative version is 0.72

and cause this crash.

Fix：
make the version is same by use this command to download demo.

```
npx react-native init SampleApp --version 0.72.6
```